# Guide/Issues with Chef solo for various tasks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Searched for almost few days and did not get the answers, so posting my questions here.
Below are my tasks which I am planning todo using chef solo (not chef server/client):

1. I want to install all software's like apache2, virgo, redis, mysql
   etc ...
2. I want to do configurations for all softwares installed
   above.
3. I want to trigger all deployments
4. I want to do localization of all property files in entire repository (App server repository, database repository, etc ...)
5. I want to create separate environments like production, staging, testing, and development environments.
6. I want to create roles like web server, database, etc ...
7. I want to add different nodes in different environments

etc ... basically all tasks like infrastructure management, configuration and deployments.

Could you please kindly suggest whether can I able to do all above tasks using chef-solo only? Or shall I move to Chef Server?

Because I am getting below error for some knife operations:

```
   knife environment list
   WARNING: No knife configuration file found
   ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem
   Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable
```

Installed chef using `curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash`

I understand that we will get the above error when I am trying to access Chef Server, but for above command I think its not required to communicate with Chef Server.

Used `"knife configure initial"` to configure Knife. After that I am commented out `client_key` and `validation_key` in `.chef/knife.rb`

Am I really required knife configuration file? If so how can I get it?

And also please suggest how can I do deployments using chef solo, I am trying using http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html#deploy-revision or any other best suggestion?

Also any other plugins which will be helpful for me to achieve all above mentioned goals.

Your help is highly appreciable.

Thanks & Regards

TopCoder

Comment: I would recommend learning to use chef-client and chef-server. Not only will you encounter cookbooks that require a chef server, you're denying yourself one of the big benefits of using chef server, it's search features that enable auto-discovery. Finally if you want to maintain separation between Dev/Test/Prod managed by one system, that is what chef environments are designed to solve, or even separate chef servers. Managing chef server is now easier that it used to be. Check out tools like Berkshelf, Spiceweasel, Vagrant, chef-zero. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Mark. Actually at this moment as the system is not complex, i am chosen chef-solo. Right now i am okie to loose powerful features like search. Any more help to achieve all the tasks mentioned in above using Chef-solo?